# authentication method when using socks4

Tags: windows, authentication, windows-authentication, socks

I have a socks4 server that I use to proxy requests from different kinds of applications (http, ftp, etc..) to their destination.

I know that socks4 does not define a way for applications to authenticate in any way (it specifies only an *optional* username when client connects to the server but it seems there is no way you can tell the client that is *should* send that information in order for the server to relay the request)

Is there a way to implement some kind of authentication over socks4 that is understood by the regular applications protocols: http, ftp, and others ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read up on how the [SOCKS protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS_%28protocol%29) works.

The second byte of a SOCKS v4/4a response is a status value that indicates whether the client's request was accepted or rejected (and why).  In this case, you would likely need to use status values `0x5C` (request failed because client is not running `identd` or it is not reachable from the server) and `0x5D` (request failed because client's `identd` could not confirm the user ID string in the request). That would make the request's username field have to contain a valid and recognizable value.  This is not true authentication, of course, since a client can run an `ident` server that reports whatever it wants.

Otherwise, switch to SOCKS v5 instead, which has support for true server-side authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the repay. I saw that also, server can specify those error codes in order for client to retry with "proper authentication" The problem is that clients seem to ignore those error codes: tried with IE and also with a chat client -> they didn't bother to ask the user to change the username.

Comment: You cannot force a client to do something, you can only report what the server needs.  In SOCKS v4/4a, there is no real username persay, it is more of a client machine identifier instead, which is why it is optional.  A SOCKS v4/4a server could reject machines that are not allowed to connect to it, but that is not really the same as authentication.  Hense SOCKS v5.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem.. Server can reject the requests but the application user ends up with non functional service without knowing what happens at all. An in case of Internet explorer you cannot force the browser to send other credentials.

Comment: accepted as answer because there is no solution to the described problem. Socks4 does not define a real authentication mechanism.